# Settings has stopped on Nokia 8

Tags: settings, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

I bought a [Nokia 8](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nokia%208) two days back, and updated it to Android Oreo 8.0.0. No more updates are available.

I have only installed some basic everyday apps such WhatsApp or Facebook.

I'm able to change wallpapers from the gallery. However, if I go to Settings > Display > Wallpaper, an error pops up, saying "Settings has stopped; open app again".

What can I do to correct this?

Clearing cache+data for the Settings app and restarting phone did not solve it. Rebooting into safe mode also did not help.

[image: settings page error]

On repeated trials, I see a slightly different screen.

[image: settings page error 2]

Comment: @beeshyams Ah, the dreaded factory reset. I'll see to it, if nothing else comes up.

Comment: That edit reinforces factory reset recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went ahead with a full reset. It was solved, but caused some [other issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189969/102422) on the side.

Trying out various approaches to reproduce the issue, I found that disabling the *Google Wallpapers* app can cause it. I do not know how it was disabled in the earlier case, or if at all that really was the cause.