# Nokia 8 does not read contents of SD Card after phone reset

Tags: external-sd, 8.0-oreo, nokia-8

Trying to solve the "[settings has stopped](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/189865/102422)" issue, I did a full reset, and then another issue came up.

On re-inserting the external SD Card, the *Files* app (or any file manager) can see the contents, but gallery and music players don't see the media. And on connecting to the PC, the SD card shows only one or two folders, and nothing else.

The SD card is a SanDisk microSDXC Class 10 64GB, which was initially formatted from within the Nokia 8 on first use, as was required for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying out [this method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134235/102422) oddly did not work, so I went ahead with formatting the SD card from within Nokia 8 once again.

Luckily I had made a backup of everything from the phone memory and from the SD card onto my PC, before I did the full reset.